# Sql transform rows to columns

Tags: sql, ms-access

Table:
Id   - Voice - Value

501  - VO01  - 11

501  - VO02  - 12

502  - VO01  - 25

502  - VO04  - 27

502  - VO05  - 28

502  - VO09  - 20

I have to extract all the **Voice** for all **Id** in this table.
Counting that Id goes from 1 to 7811, i want to extract all different Voice per every Id with one query. I would have one record like

**Id, voice1, value1, voice2, value2, .. voiceN, valueN.**

In this case:

501, VO01, 11, VO02, 12

502, VO01, 25, VO04, 27, VO05, 28, VO09, 20

Thank you

Comment: sql server or access?

Comment: A quick google send me to another topic on this site:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745042/efficiently-convert-rows-to-columns-in-sql-server-2008